# Why is difference between sqlContext.read.load and sqlContext.read.text?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I am only trying to read a textfile into a pyspark RDD, and I am noticing huge differences between `sqlContext.read.load` and `sqlContext.read.text`.

```
s3_single_file_inpath='s3a://bucket-name/file_name'

indata = sqlContext.read.load(s3_single_file_inpath, format='com.databricks.spark.csv', header='true', inferSchema='false',sep=',')
indata = sqlContext.read.text(s3_single_file_inpath)
```

The `sqlContext.read.load` command above fails with

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o227.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.csv. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
```

But the second one succeeds?

Now, I am confused by this because all of the resources I see online say to use `sqlContext.read.load` including this one: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.html.

It is not clear to me when to use which of these to use when.  Is there a clear distinction between these?

Comment: What are the _"huge differences"_? I can only see one in your question that one fails while the other does not.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is difference between sqlContext.read.load and sqlContext.read.text?

`sqlContext.read.load` assumes `parquet` as the data source format while `sqlContext.read.text` assumes `text` format.

With `sqlContext.read.load` you can define the data source format using `format` parameter.

---

Depending on the version of Spark **1.6** vs **2.x** you may or may not load an external Spark package to have support for **csv** format.

As of Spark 2.0 you no longer have to load [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) Spark package since (quoting the [official documentation](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#csv-data-source-for-apache-spark-1x)):

> NOTE: This functionality has been inlined in Apache Spark 2.x. This package is in maintenance mode and we only accept critical bug fixes.

That would explain why you got confused as you may have been using Spark 1.6.x and have not loaded the Spark package to have `csv` support.

> Now, I am confused by this because all of the resources I see online say to use `sqlContext.read.load` including this one: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.html.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.html is for Spark 1.6.1 when `spark-csv` Spark package was not part of Spark. It happened in Spark 2.0.

---

> It is not clear to me when to use which of these to use when. Is there a clear distinction between these?

There's none actually *iff* you use Spark 2.x.

If however you use Spark 1.6.x, `spark-csv` has to be loaded separately using `--packages` option (as described in [Using with Spark shell](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#using-with-spark-shell)):

> This package can be added to Spark using the `--packages` command line option. For example, to include it when starting the spark shell

---

As a matter of fact, you can still use `com.databricks.spark.csv` format explicitly in Spark 2.x as it's recognized internally.

Comment: so you mean that irrespective of whether you use `spark.read.csv()`/`spark.read.text()` or `spark.read.load()`, it is one and the same thing and has no distinction for Spark 2.x ?

Comment: Pretty much yes. There are some optimizations that data sources can use to make the loading more effective (e.g. schema inference), but that's just minor point in the discussion.

Comment: Oh that's very reassuring. Many thanks Jacek. If I may ask you another question - while using these import functions, can we specify the `numberOfPartitions`? Or is it that we have to resort to `repartition()` afterwards? If you want, I can post it as another question and intimate you so that you could answer it there. Please let me know.

Comment: Number of partitions? No. It's orthogonal to a data source so it does not have to deal with such low-level things like partitions.

Comment: Well, your reasoning is quite high level for me to understand at the moment :) I will investigate it further. Thank you so much Jacek.

Comment: Hi Jacek, would you mind answering it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53431989/pyspark-partitioning-and-hashing-multiple-dataframes-then-joining your perspective will be very valuable.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is:

- `text` is a built-in input format in Spark 1.6
- `com.databricks.spark.csv` is a third party package in Spark 1.6

To use third party Spark CSV (no longer needed in Spark 2.0) you have to follow the instructions on `spark-csv` site, for example provide

```
 --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0
```

argument with `spark-submit` / `pyspark` commands.

Beyond that `sqlContext.read.formatName(...)` is a syntactic sugar for `sqlContext.read.format("formatName")` and `sqlContext.read.load(..., format=formatName)`.