# PySpark: Partitioning and hashing multiple dataframes, then joining

Tags: python, apache-spark, hash, pyspark, hadoop-partitioning

**Background:** I am working with clinical data with a lot of different `.csv/.txt` files. All these files are *patientID* based, but with different fields. I am importing these files into `DataFrames`, which I will `join` at a later stage after first processing each of these `DataFrames` individually. I have shown examples of two `DataFrames` below (`df_A` and `df_B`). Similarly, I have multiple `DataFrames` - `df_A`, `df_B`, `df_C` .... `df_J` and I will `join` all of them at a later stage.

```
df_A = spark.read.schema(schema).format("csv").load(...)....            # Just an example
df_A.show(3)
#Example 1:
+----------+-----------------+
| patientID|   diagnosis_code|
+----------+-----------------+
|       A51|             XIII|
|       B22|               VI|
|       B13|               XV|
+----------+-----------------+
df_B.show(3)
#Example 2:
+-----------+----------+-------+-------------+--------+
|  patientID|  hospital|   city|  doctor_name|    Bill|
+-----------+----------+-------+-------------+--------+
|        A51|   Royal H| London|C.Braithwaite|  451.23|
|        B22|Surgery K.|  Leeds|      J.Small|   88.00|
|        B22|Surgery K.|  Leeds|      J.Small|  102.01|
+-----------+----------+-------+-------------+--------+
print("Number of partitions: {}".format(df_A.rdd.getNumPartitions()))# Num of partitions: 1
print("Partitioner: {}".format(df_A.rdd.partitioner))                # Partitioner: None

Number of partitions: 1 #With other DataFrames I get more partitions.
Partitioner: None
```

After reading all these `.csv/.txt` files into `DataFrames`, I can see that for some `DataFrames` the data is distributed on just 1 `partition` (like above), but for others `DataFrames`, there could be more partitions, depending upon the size of the corresponding `.csv/.txt` file, which in turn influences number of blocks created (128 MB default size in `HDFS`).  We also don't have a `partitioner` at the moment.

**Question:** Now, is it not a good idea to redistribute these `DataFrames` on multiple `partitions`, `hashed` on the basis of *patientID*, so that we can avoid as much `shuffling` as possible when we `join()` these multiple `DataFrames`? If indeed, this is what is desired, then should I do repartitioning on *patientID* basis and have a same `partitioner` for all `DataFrames`(not sure if it's possible)? I have also read that `DataFrame` does everything on it's own, but should we not specify `hashing` according to column *patientID*?

I will really appreciate if someone can provide some useful links or cues on what optimization strategy should one employ when dealing with these multiple `DataFrames`, all *patientID* based.

Comment: In general if dataframe is small enough to occupy a single partition it is also small enough to be automatically broadcasted, so the problem is non existent. And in broader sense *repartition is shuffle*, so if it is one off operation, it is a waste of time.

Comment: Well, I have many dataframes and some of them are very big, occupying some 50 partitions (number of my cores) by default. So, when I will join them, I will have a lot of shuffling to do on partitions if all the dataframes are not having same partitioner. That's why I am thinking to partition all dataframes, on let's say 50 partitions, and then use same hashing function to partition (don't know if it's possible) to partition on all dataframes. If you have any suggestion, that may be very helpful.